# Multiple loops when inserting document in MongoDB database with Java drive

Tags: java, matlab, mongodb

Firstly, it is my first application with mongoDB, and I am not a Java expert neither. I am using Java libraries with Matlab...

So here the code sample that causes me troubles:

```
javaaddpath('C:\Users\######\Documents\MATLAB\JAR\mongo-2.10.1.jar')
import com.mongodb.*;
mongoClient = MongoClient();
db = mongoClient.getDB( 'MonroeLossErrorDB' );
coll = db.getCollection('Traces');

fileList = getFiles();
for i=1:350
   file = fielList{i};
   [x, samples] = getSamples(file);
   doc = BasicDBObject();
   doc.put('filename', file);
   doc.put('samples',samples)
   doc.put('x',x);
   coll.insert(doc,WriteConcern.SAFE);
end
```

Everything works without any error, when I examine the database, there are indeed 350 tuples (documents) but....
The script takes A LOT OF TIME to execute. I restricted it to 350 but there are thousands of loops I wanted to do. When I debugged my script, I noticed that for some reasons, the loop was restarting from i=1, like if somewhere the script was called again and again. For example, after iteration #22, the script restart, then after iteration #46 it restarts again. When I stop the current process, I am rethrown to the previous process that stops at iteration #46. When this one is also stopped, I am rethrown to the previous one that stops at iteration #22 and finally the entire script ends if I stop it again.

Is there a link with the database file size ? I mean, mongoDB start with a file of 16MB, then 32MB and so on. Does it means that after filling the first file, the script is executed again to fill a bigger file, then restart for another bigger and so on until the file could contain all documents ?

Why does my script restart many times before ending ?

Comment: I am by no means a DB guy, but If you are doing bulk insertion, indexes will slow you down. Perhaps its better to add them after you've loaded the data. As for the restarting issue, that does sound strange. You could add a [progressbar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html) updated each iteration, that way you'll know if anything weird is happening with the loop variable `i`

Comment: Just a comment - you don't need to use WriteConcern.SAFE when you're using the 2.10 version of the MongoDB driver, this is the default.  You can simply use coll.insert(doc)

Comment: Is it possible something is calling this script multiple times?  I.e. that the problem is outside of the script itself, but is calling this script many times?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comments. Unfortunatly, this script is standalone and nothing calls it outside. I added the writeconcern to be sure it is in safe mode as while debugging, the loop was called multiple times, and I was wondering if it was the fault of the writing in the db. The moment the lopp is restarting is random. The last time I tried, everything has gone fine, the loop ran just one time... Very strange.